# Плагин для scroll не вызывающий проблем с отображением

Tags: jquery, css, плагин

Всем привет. Кто может посоветовать плагин для более мягкого скролла для всей страницы,а не для отдельного элемента? Есть одно требование-на странице используется несколько position:fixed для целых секция(для отображения слоями) и допустим при опробывании CustomScroll появляется проблема с отображением-слои с более высоким z-index начинают занимать не всю ширину экрана(хотя стоит width:100%) и из-за этого слои которые с position:fixed и более маленьким z-index становятся видны пикселей эдак на 20(они почему то занимают 100% ширины экрана). проблема не в css, так как пробовал менять множество свойств.Код тут отобразить вряд ли получится, так как надо выкладывать слишком большой кусок, но думаю и так понятна суть)

Comment: Попробуйте `width:100%` заменить на `width:100vw`. Пальцем в небо без кода.

Comment: попробовал-без результата.хотя этот вариант уже пробовал.С удовольствием бы предоставил код, но он реально оч много места займет.Нужен просто самый неконфликтный плагин.нет необходимости изменять что-то кроме плавности именно скролла страницы(то есть не нужны никакие кастомные штучки со скроллбаром).А суть вообще простая-1 секция во всю ширину и высоту экрана с position:fixed, за ней несколько секций контента с более высоким z-index и в завершении футтер с position:fixed..так вот при применении каких-либо плагинов(которые пробовал)футтер и 1 секция снизу выглядывает под контентом на 20px

Comment: ну примерно на 20px, это не конкретная величина.

Comment: mCustomScrollbar пробовали?

Comment: и его пробовал...все равно зазор появляется...мне бы плагин какой-то, который не создает контейнер обертку, а работает напрямую только лишь со скролом..искал, что-то ничего не попалось такого...